# Strange styling and jquery rendering issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, themes

I am facing a strange issue with styles and jquery. For some of my themes, styles and jquery is emitting twice. I am not able to reproduce this issue locally, however, it is happening on server. I have a skin file and the device constraint applied already. But for some reason, my mobile css is also rendering on normal browser. Is this something related to IIS and Asp.Net or something else. I suspect it might be something related to encoding? I am not able to figure out an exact cause.

Let me clarify my problem with example. In one theme, which is working good, styles are rendering like:

```
one.css
two.css
three.css
```

Other theme which have the issue is rendering like this:

```
mobile.css
one.css
two.css
three.css
one.css#2
two.css#2
three.css#2
```

One more thing, if I download the theme and then upload with/without making any change, it started rendering correctly.

Can anybody give me any insight? I will truly appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: what does `emitting twice` even mean?

Comment: Same style sheet is applying two times e.g. style.css and style.css#2 when I inspect in firebug. Also styling is not caring for device constraint e.g. mobile.css is rendering in normal browser (firefox) which should not be. Same thing is working perfect in other theme.

Comment: Post your HTML part where you are including css

Comment: I am including the css using the skin file and custom web control. Same is working in one theme but not in other, although both are same.

Comment: How can be confirmed it is not an encoding issue?